# Suspended Invoke-SQLcmd Query - Database in use

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I am trying to automate the process of importing GNAF (location dataset for Australia) into a new database. 
The problem I am having is that when I try to the database and recreate it I get an error saying the database is in use:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot drop database "GNAF" because it is currently in use. At line:11 char:5
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysd ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand   Invoke-Sqlcmd : Database 'GNAF' already exists. Choose a different database name. At line:15 char:5
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "CREATE DATABASE GNAF" -serverinstance $Serv ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

In the activity monitor for SSMS it shows:

[image]

This is the function that is being called:

```
function importQNAF {

$ScriptPath = "C:\Users\owain.esau\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\TRIS Database Anon\" # change to pwd for live
$QNAFpath1 = ( $ScriptPath + "GNAF\G-NAF\G-NAF AUGUST 2017\Standard\" )
$QNAFpath2 = ( $ScriptPath + "GNAF\G-NAF\G-NAF AUGUST 2017\Authority Code\" )
$GNAF_ImportData_Path = ( $ScriptPath + "\SQLScripts\GNAF_ImportData.sql" )

(Get-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path).replace("Powershell To Change#1", $QNAFpath1) | Set-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path
(Get-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path).replace("Powershell To Change#2", $QNAFpath2) | Set-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path

## Drop and Create Table
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name ='GNAF')
                      BEGIN
                        ALTER DATABASE GNAF SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                        DROP DATABASE GNAF;
                      END
                    ;" -serverinstance $ServerAddress;
Start-Sleep -s 5;
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "CREATE DATABASE GNAF" -serverinstance $ServerAddress;
Start-Sleep -s 5;

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile ( $ScriptPath + "SQLScripts\GNAF_CreateTables.sql" ) -serverinstance $ServerAddress;

try {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile ( $ScriptPath + "SQLScripts\GNAF_ImportData.sql" ) -serverinstance $ServerAddress -querytimeout 0;
} catch {
     if ($error -match  "Access is denied.") {
        Write-Host "[!] ERROR: Access denied to GNAF folder."
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------"
        Write-Host "You have two options: "
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "    1) Give MSSQLSERVER full access to" $ScriptPath
        Write-Host "    2) Copy the1 folder: " $ScriptPath"GNAF to the MSSQL Source folder (C:\Program Files\SQL Server)" 

        Do {
            switch(Read-Host "Please choose an action (1 or 2)") {
                1 {
                    $Acl = (Get-Item $ScriptPath).GetAccessControl('Access');
                    $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow");
                    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar);
                    Set-Acl $ScriptPath $Acl;
                    importQNAF;
                }
                2 { Write-Host "Not coded yet"; }
                default { "Invalid Entry, must be 1 or 2"; }
            }
        } Until ($choice -eq 1 -or $choice -eq 2)
    }
}
```

(Get-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path).replace($QNAFpath1, "Powershell To Change#1") | Set-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path
   (Get-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path).replace($QNAFpath2, "Powershell To Change#2") | Set-Content $GNAF_ImportData_Path
}
The script I am using to actually import the data into SQL server is almost identical to the one found on this page:

https://www.rednotebluenote.com/2016/04/importing-psma-geocoded-national-address-file-g-naf-to-sql-server/

It works fine directly in SSMS. Also, I don't think my error match is picking up the correct error, instead it is matching to all errors.

--- Update ----------------------------------------------

Managed to get it to run when i restart the MSSQLSERVER service at the start of the function.

The problem now is that it times out:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
BULK INSERT [MB_2011] FROM 'C:\Users\owain.esau\OneDrive\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\TRIS Database Anon\GNAF\G-NAF\G-NAF AUGUST 2017\Standard\ACT_MB_2011_psv.psv'  WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = 
'\n', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWS_PER_BATCH=100000, TABLOCK) 
At line:30 char:9
+         Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile ( $ScriptPath + "SQLScripts\GNAF_Imp ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

It only runs for around 45 seconds before this error pops up, the actual script being run takes around 3 - 5 minutes run in SSMA.

(The function has been updated a bit)

Comment: Please stop restarting Sql Server. You got other issues that are "resolved" via restart. It's a bit like curing a headache by hitting your thumb with a hammer. Sure, your head doesn't hurt anymore, but is it sensible?

Comment: Was more a quick and easy fix as i knew how to restart it from PowerShell and since this was on a localhost with no databases on it, it wasnt an issue. Ill switch it to the suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate any existing, open connections to the database.

Here's the easiest method (it basically forces all other connections to be killed)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name ='GNAF')
  BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE GNAF SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE GNAF;
  END
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just figured this out after restarting the sql service. I also had to add -querytimeout 0 to the second invoke-sqlcmd call. Is your method better than just restarting the service?

Comment: It doesn't require the service to be restarted.

Comment: I finally managed to have this working with this code. However, in order to have a multiline command in a powershell script, at the end of each line it is necessary to use a space followed by the grave accent (backtick). Without this, we would have to inline the whole command. As an example, the line containing the `Drop` command would be written as follows:


DROP DATABASE GNAF; `